# Bootstrap templating? can i use Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, handlebars.js, templating

I have been re-building a site with Bootstrap, but I know that many of the links will change as I build the site. It seems the best plan to use HTML templating to produce the links in the navbar.

However, I just can't get it to work at all. I am guessing there may be some issue with the collapsable navbar using javascript, and when each function runs. This is just a guess, I am a beginner.

This is the HTML - (the handlebars link is in the header)

```
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> 
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
            </button>
            <nav class="navbar-collapse collapse" role="navigation">


                <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
                    <li><a href="{{home}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">About<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="{{intention}}">Intention</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{membership}}">Membership</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{genealogy}}">Genealogy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{contact}}">Contact</a></li>

                        </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Writings<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="{{poetry}}">Poetry</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{articles}}">Articles</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{lectures}}">Lectures</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{quranic}}">Qur’anic Study</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{stories}}">Sufi Stories</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{thoughts}}">Thoughts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{reviews}}">Book Reviews</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{library}}">Library</a></li>

                        </ul>
                        </li>
                    <li><a href="{{sharib}}">Sharib Press</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{99names}}">99 Names</a></li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Persian Pages<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                           <li><a href="{{hafiz}}">Hafiz Shirazi</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{firstline}}">First Line index</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{glossary}}">Glossary</a></li>

                        </ul>
                      </li>

                      <li><a href="{{ajmer}}">Ajmer</a></li>
                      <li><a href="{{konya}}">Konya</a></li>

                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Images<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                           <li><a href="{{photos}}">Photos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{art}}">Art Gallery</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{shrines}}">Sufi Shrines</a></li>

                        </ul>
                      </li>

                </ul>


            </nav>

        </script>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

This is the script file -

```
var source   = $("#some-template").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var data = { 
    home : "/home.html",
    etc.
};
  $("#content-placeholder").html(template(data));
```

I copied this from a tutorial mostly, and the parent div has the correct ID.

Is it even possible to use templating in this case?

Answer (score 0):

OK incase anyone stumbles across this having the same issue, there was only a small issue. 
The fact that one of the data names in the script began with a number '99' (i didn't show this in my question as I assumend the data was fine). To solve this I simply put it in quotation marks.